# Date Picker startDate and endDate Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, datepicker

I want to show **UIDatePickerView** start date calendar for 180 days only and when user will select any start date in 180 days, he will click on end date button so date picker should show only 89 days from the start date and selected start date should not be an end date

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `addingTimeInterval` method of `Date`.

```
datePicker.minimumDate = startDate?.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * 90) //  90 days interval offset
```

Now for `endDate`, DatePicker always display 90 days forward date then start Date.

And if you want display 180 days from current date on `startDate` then you can manage startDate like below.

```
datePicker.minimumDate = Date() //Today's date
datePicker.maximumDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * 180) //180 days forward time from today.
```

It will only  display 180 days duration in datePicker.

Comment: Thank you .. let me see if its wok :) but thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @King, Check updated answer where, 180 days duration of startDate is  Added.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add A Button And Give them Connection
 @IBOutlet weak var DateSelect: UIButton!

// Add "UIDatePicker" to your project and Give them connection
@IBOutlet weak var fromedatepicker: UIDatePicker! 

// . and  Make an Action Button to "UIDatePicker"
@IBAction func fromedatepicker(_ sender: Any) {
    let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
    let currentDate = NSDate()
    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    let minDate = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponents as DateComponents, to: currentDate as Date, options: NSCalendar.Options(rawValue: 0))

    dateComponents.month = 3 //or you can change month = day(90)           

    let maxDate = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponents as DateComponents, to: currentDate as Date, options: NSCalendar.Options(rawValue: 0))
    self.fromedatepicker.maximumDate = maxDate
    self.fromedatepicker.minimumDate = minDate

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: fromedatepicker.date)
    print(strDate)

    DateSelect.DateSelect.titleLabel?.text =  strDate    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and I really appreciate it but what about the start dates ?? That I have to show only 180 days ??? And when user will select any date from start date so that date shouldnt be in end date only 89 days enddate calendar should show...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only 90 days from start date than:

```
@IBOutlet var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date //To show only Date format for date picker

    //Get current Date 
    var currentDate = Date()

    let addDays: TimeInterval = (60 * 60 * 24 * 180) //Add 180 for initial Days

    currentDate = currentDate.addingTimeInterval(addDays)

    datePicker.minimumDate = Date()  //Start with current date
    datePicker.maximumDate = currentDate //End with current date + 180 days.

}

//Action for DatePicker
@IBAction func displayDay(_ sender: Any) {

   let choosenDate = datePicker.date

   //If you want to set Date format for selected picker date
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"

   let selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: choosenDate)
   print(selectedDate)

   //You can use different datePicker object to set below endDate as +90 days because if you you same date picker it will always add selected date +90 days to date picker. 
   let addDays: TimeInterval = (60 * 60 * 24 * 89) //Add 89 Days

   //Set Start Date as choosen Date
   datePicker.minimumDate = choosenDate

   //Set Max Date as choosen Date + 89 Days
   datePicker.maximumDate = Date(timeInterval: addDays, since: choosenDate)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and I really appreciate it but what about the start dates ?? That I have to show only 180 days ??? And when user will select any date from start date so that date shouldnt be in end date only 89 days enddate calendar should show...

Answer (score 0):

```
    var datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker?.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker?.minimumDate = Date() // this to set the start date today
    //this to set the date range you can change " byAdding: .year " to "byAdding: .month" if you went the range by month or to "byAdding: .day"
    let nextDays = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 14, to: Date()) 
    datePicker?.maximumDate = nextDays ?? Date() // this to set the maximum date
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, SO really appreciates your contribution towards this question, however, its lacking information and a strong description of the code you have supplied. Please update your answer to have more information.

Comment: Hi I.T Delinquent, I just updated my answer with some comments